# Changing CSS grid column sizes based on content?

Tags: css, vue.js, alignment, css-grid

Struggling with `CSS grid` and could do with a bit of help.

I've got a `<section>` item with 4 items, these should be separated 2 on the left, 2 on the right, centered vertically.

However, when my Vue component state variable changes, the items are filtered down to just the two on the right.

How do I keep the correct format of the grid so the two columns stay on the right when there are less items in the grid?

[image: basic example of the grid]

So far I have this for the main outer div...

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
grid-column-gap: 1.25em;
align-items: center;
```

and this for my two inner right divs

```
display: grid;
justify-content: right;
align-content: center;
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

For your inner div:

Instead of using `justify-content: right;`, which isn't a thing, use: `justify-content: flex-end;`

`Justify-content: flex-end;` places everything at the end, depending what the `flex-direction` is. The same counts for `justify-content: flex-start;` of course, which places everything at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way with extra div to hold right items:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, auto));
  grid-column-gap: 1.25em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.right {
  justify-self: end;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.item {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```